# Orders repeat based on condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Based on data need to increase records 2.5 times of existing orders (any orders of that date) based on date wise and id should be unique when increase orders. We can prefix any number starting on id values.

Table : emp

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp]
(
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [sal] [int] NULL,
    [dos] [date] NULL
) 
GO

INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [sal], [dos]) 
VALUES (1, N'balu', 10, CAST(N'2016-02-01' AS Date))

INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [sal], [dos]) 
VALUES (2, N'ravi', 12, CAST(N'2016-02-01' AS Date))

INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [sal], [dos]) 
VALUES (3, N'hari', 20, CAST(N'2016-03-07' AS Date))
```

Example: date is 2016-02-01 have 2 records need to increase records 2.5 timesof that is 2 * 2.5 = 5

Final this 2016-02-01  date need to get 5 records for that date similar to other dates

If we take another date is 2016-03-07 this date is have only one record  here 1 * 2.5 =2.5. here we can consider 3 records instead of 2.5 count we can round of the value.

Final this date  2016-03-07 need to show 3 records

Final I need to output like below (I have given id, name, sal, dos values sample, we can given values based on date wise and increase 2.5 times of existing order)

```
id  |name   |sal    |dos
1   |balu   |10     |2016-02-01
2   |ravi   |12     |2016-02-01
11  |balu   |10     |2016-02-01
22  |ravi   |12     |2016-02-01
31  |balu   |10     |2016-02-01
3   |hari   |20     |2016-03-07
23  |hari   |20     |2016-03-07
33  |op     |10     |2016-03-07
```

I have tried like `emp` table records inserted into another `tempemp` table and tempemp related ids values updates if 1 is there then updated 11

Similar to 2 and need one more records and again I have used another tempemp1 table (temptable) and insert emp record one on that data and updated that records
again that record loaded in to emp table. Final I got 5 records on 2016-02-01 and similar to another date.

Here I can do for two dates. but this logic is not working when I have more than 100k records with different dates and very difficult to do manually date by date

How to write a query to achieve this task in SQL Server?

Comment: Is there some kind of misunderstand what percentages mean? 2.5% increase for 2 orders is not 5 orders, it's 2.05 orders.

Comment: Hi James need to increase 2.5 times of existing orders based on date wise.